# Facebook Signature incorrect

Tags: facebook

I'm Verifying the signature just like this: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/ind … _Signature

but there's something wrong:

when creating md5 from concatenated string (cookies: expires, session_key, ss, user) plus application secret ... i'm getting different results as it follows:

Example:
cookie with signature value: 093dc0c322c04cd35bc2c1d83137219d
md5(cookies plus secret) :  93dc0c322c04cd35bc2c1d83137219d

The only difference here is the first digit.

I was doing this signature verification without any problems until now.

I was using the API key and Application secret of an application that i've created on facebook account. Now, i've created a new application on my enterprise facebook page and i'm using the API key and application secret of this new application. Now, it's not working

Does anyone knows what happened?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need the leading zero.

Comment: I've tried again this morning and the generated md5 signature, sent by facebook was: 3104608680b4912ab24875822aa76dee
the md5 signature calculated by me was: 314608680b4912ab24875822aa76dee

as you ca see, the only difference is one zero in the middle of the string. :s

Comment: how are you calculating the md5?